# Restrict zip codes for custom shipping method is not working after hide the shipping method

Tags: magento

we are really facing very strange problem here.

we are using 1.9.0.1 and custom shipping method.

We Hide Shipping Method Step in checkout using answer gave by @Marius here :

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53355/remove-shipping-steps-in-onepage-checkout

But we have one problem here.

we allowed only some zip codes to place an order.

but here its allowing for all zip codes when user enter first time.

once user enter zip code and click on "Continue" button, it will go to next step [payment methods]

[image]

**Payment method step**

[image]

Than if user again come to Previous step and enter same zip code and if user click on "Continue"

button, than it will show error message in pop up - "Invalid shipping method"

[image]

This is fine, but **it should not allow when user enter zip code for first time also.**

Before everything was fine, once we hide shipping method , this problem happened. but for default shipping method it is working fine.

ex site : [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/) & zip code  000000

we are using this code for restricting zip codes and finding shipping charges.

```
<?php
class extension_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    /*  Use group alias */
    protected $_code = 'mpperproductshipping';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){        
    $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();
    $restrictedCodes = array(

110001,
110002

); //restricted values. they can come from anywhere
    if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) { 
         return false;

    }   

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        /* Edited by vikas_mageworx */
        $postcode=$request->getDestPostcode();
        $countrycode=$request->getDestCountry();
        $items=$request->getAllItems();
        /* End Editing by vikas_mageworx */

        $postcode=str_replace('-', '', $postcode);
        $shippingdetail=array();

        /*  one start */
        $shippostaldetail=array('countrycode'=>$countrycode,'postalcode'=>$postcode,'items'=>$items);
       /*  one end  */



        foreach($items as $item) {
            $proid=$item->getProductId();
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                    $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                    if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                        $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $mpassignModel = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $partner = $mpassignModel->getSellerId();
            } else {
                $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')
                    ->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$proid));
                foreach($collection as $temp) {
                    $partner=$temp->getUserid();
                }
            }

            $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid)->getWeight();
            $weight=$product*$item->getQty();
            if(count($shippingdetail)==0){
                array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
            }else{
                $shipinfoflag=true;
                $index=0;
                foreach($shippingdetail as $itemship){
                    if($itemship['seller_id']==$partner){
                        $itemship['items_weight']=$itemship['items_weight']+$weight;
                        $itemship['product_name']=$itemship['product_name'].",".$item->getName();
                        $itemship['item_id']=$itemship['item_id'].",".$item->getId();
                        $itemship['qty']=$itemship['qty']+$item->getQty();
                        $shippingdetail[$index]=$itemship;
                        $shipinfoflag=false;
                    }
                    $index++;
                }
                if($shipinfoflag==true){
                    array_push($shippingdetail,array('seller_id'=>$partner,'items_weight'=>$weight,'product_name'=>$item->getName(),'qty'=>$item->getQty(),'item_id'=>$item->getId()));
                }
            }
        }
        $shippingpricedetail=$this->getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail);

        if($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']!==""){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingCustomError($shippingpricedetail['errormsg']);
            return $result;
        }
        /*store shipping in session*/
        $shippingAll=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('shippinginfo');
        $shippingAll[$this->_code]=$shippingpricedetail['shippinginfo'];
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('shippinginfo',$shippingAll);

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));
        /* Use method name */
        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/name'));
        $method->setCost($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']);
        $method->setPrice($shippingpricedetail['handlingfee']); 
        $result->append($method);
        return $result; 
    }

public function getShippingPricedetail($shippingdetail,$shippostaldetail) {
        $shippinginfo=array();
        $handling=0;
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $customerAddress = $session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();


/* Edited by vikas_boy */
$customerPostCode = $shippostaldetail['postalcode'];
$items = $shippostaldetail['items'];
 /* End Editing by vikas_boy  */


 /* one  */

        foreach($shippingdetail as $shipdetail) {
            $seller = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($shipdetail['seller_id']);
            $sellerAddress = $seller->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
            $distance = $this->getDistanse($sellerAddress->getPostcode(),$customerPostCode);
            // echo "distance ".$distance;die;
            $price = 0;
            $itemsarray=explode(',',$shipdetail['item_id']);
            foreach($items as $item) {
                $proid=$item->getProductId();
                $options=$item->getProductOptions();
                $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
                if(!$mpassignproductId) {
                    foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                        $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                        if($temp['mpassignproduct_id']) {
                            $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($proid))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                $mpshippingcharge = 0;
                $localDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/local_shipping_distance');
                $regionalDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/regional_shipping_distance');
                $stateDistance = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/mpperproductshipping/state_shipping_distance');
                if(in_array($item->getId(),$itemsarray)) {
                    if($mpassignproductId) {
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getLocalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId)->getStateShippingCharge();
                        }
                    } else {
                         // echo "imte ".$item->getProductId();
                        if($distance < $localDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpLocalShippingCharge();
                            // echo "imte ".$item->getProductId();
                            // echo "ship ".$mpshippingcharge;
                        } elseif($distance > $localDistance && $distance < $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpRegionalShippingCharge();
                        } elseif($distance > $regionalDistance) {
                            $mpshippingcharge=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId())->getMpStateShippingCharge();
                        }   
                    }

                    /* tt */
                    // echo "test ".$mpshippingcharge;die;
                    if(!is_numeric($mpshippingcharge)){
                        $price=$price+floatval($this->getConfigData('defalt_ship_amount')* floatval($item->getQty()));
                    }else{
                        $price=$price+($mpshippingcharge * floatval($item->getQty()));
                    }

                }
            }

            $handling = $handling+$price;
            $submethod = array(array('method'=>Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'),'cost'=>$price,'error'=>0));
            array_push($shippinginfo,array('seller_id'=>$shipdetail['seller_id'],'methodcode'=>$this->_code,'shipping_ammount'=>$price,'product_name'=>$shipdetail['product_name'],'submethod'=>$submethod,'item_ids'=>$shipdetail['item_id']));
        }
        $msg="";
        return array('handlingfee'=>$handling,'shippinginfo'=>$shippinginfo,'errormsg'=>$msg);
    }


 /* one end */

    /* tt start */

    private function getDistanse($origin,$destination) {
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$origin.",india&destinations=".$destination.",india&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response_all = json_decode($response);
        $distance = $response_all->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value / 1000;
        if($distance==0){
            $zips = array(
                $origin,$destination
                // ... etc ...
            );

            $geocoded = array();
            $serviceUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:%s&sensor=false";
            $curl = curl_init();
            foreach ($zips as $zip) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, sprintf($serviceUrl, urlencode($zip)));
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                $data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
                $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                if ($info['http_code'] != 200) {
                    // Request failed
                } else if ($data->status !== 'OK') {
                    // Something happened, or there are no results
                } else {
                    $geocoded[$zip] =$data->results[0]->geometry->location;
                }
            }
            $distance=$this->DistAB($geocoded[$zips[0]]->lat,$geocoded[$zips[0]]->lng,$geocoded[$zips[1]]->lat,$geocoded[$zips[1]]->lng);

            }
        return $distance;
    }


public function DistAB($lat_a,$lon_a,$lat_b,$lon_b)

      { 

        $measure_unit = 'kilometers';

        $measure_state = false;

        $measure = 0;

        $error = '';

          $delta_lat = $lat_b - $lat_a ;
          $delta_lon = $lon_b - $lon_a ;
          $earth_radius = 6372.795477598;

          $alpha    = $delta_lat/2;
          $beta     = $delta_lon/2;
          $a        = sin(deg2rad($alpha)) * sin(deg2rad($alpha)) + cos(deg2rad($this->lat_a)) * cos(deg2rad($this->lat_b)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) * sin(deg2rad($beta)) ;
          $c        = asin(min(1, sqrt($a)));
          $distance = 2*$earth_radius * $c;
          $distance = round($distance, 4);

         $measure = $distance;
         return $measure;

      }

    }

 /*  tt end */
```

**onepage.phtml** : `app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/checkout/onepage.phml`

```
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('varien/accordion.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/opcheckout.js') ?>"></script>
<ol class="opc" id="checkoutSteps">
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
<?php if (!$this->getChild($_stepId) || !$this->getChild($_stepId)->isShow()): continue; endif; $i++ ?>
    <li id="opc-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="section<?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['allow'])?' allow':'' ?><?php echo !empty($_stepInfo['complete'])?' saved':'' ?>">
        <div class="step-title">
            <span class="number"><?php echo $i ?>.</span>
            <h2><?php echo $_stepInfo['label'] ?></h2>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $this->__('Edit') ?></a>
        </div>
        <div id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_stepId) ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var accordion = new Accordion('checkoutSteps', '.step-title', true);
    <?php if($this->getActiveStep()): ?>
    accordion.openSection('opc-<?php echo $this->getActiveStep() ?>');
    <?php endif ?>
    var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
        progress: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/progress') ?>',
        review: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/review') ?>',
        saveMethod: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveMethod') ?>',
        failure: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'}
    );
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Since these are the restricted Codes shouldn't it be `in_array` and not `!in_array`

Comment: sorry, these are allowed zip codes, i mentioned wrongly in question.

Comment: what i mean is only zip codes enter in code should allow to place an order, all other zip codes are restricted zip codes.

Comment: Can you output the result of postcode `Mage::log('$postcode ' . $postcode);` because str_replace('-', '', $postcode)

Comment: can you please inform where i need to add this code : `Mage::log('$postcode ' . $postcode);` after which line in above code. also how to check the output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is bind a javascript event to the input field of pincode and send the request everytime when someone is typing in the pincode like this:

```
<input type = "text" onchange = "myfun(this.value)">
```

And then bind a javascript function myfun to it and make an AJAX call to your pincode checking controller, this will take the value once you finish typing into the text box

Otherwise you can also go with

```
<input type = "text" onkeypress = "myfun(this.value)">
```

And then again bind a javascript function myfun to it and make an AJAX call to your pincode checking controller, this will take the value even when you are typing into the text box

Ok, in your onepage template, write this code:

```
jQuery('#billing:postcode').change(function(){
    // your ajax call to your controller where you are verifying your pincode, something like:

       jQuery.ajax({
           url: "path/to/your/controller",
           data: this.value,
           success: function(response){
                        if(response == true){
                            // your success action
                        } else{
                           //your failure action
                        }
                    }
       })
})
```

Comment: You have to put this code in the onepage checkout page phtml template, if you can put that code here then I may be able to help you out

Comment: are you asking for `app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/checkout/onepage.phml` code ?

Comment: Just put the above code in your script tag and run it

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo can you help me for Magento 2.3.2 please